# RabbitMq connectionString with multiple nodes

Tags: rabbitmq, connection-string

I need to connect my app in a clustered rabbitmq, using connection string.

- *amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/myvhost*
- *amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5673/myvhost*
- *amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5674/myvhost*

But the docs in rabbitmq page, only shows samples with a simple one node.

I also tried like this, without success:

- *amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672,localhost:5673,localhost:5674/myvhost*